# Trying to load data into databse through web browser: save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'ship'

Tags: python, html, django

I'm at a total loss as to why I get this error. When I run similar code in the python shell I never get this error but when I try to do this through the web browser I get this error. Any idea why this happens? FYI, I'm a total beginner.

Models:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Hull (models.Model):
    hull = models.CharField(max_length = 33, )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.hull

class Hull_Spec(models.Model):
    ship = models.ForeignKey(Hull, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    speed = models.FloatField()
    depth = models.FloatField()
    remarks  = models.CharField(max_length =300)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.remarks
```

views

```
def new_ship (response):
    x = Hull
    x.objects.create(hull = response.POST.get('ship'))
    Z = Hull(hull = response.POST.get('ship'))
    Z.hull_spec_set.create(speed = response.POST.get('speed'), depth = response.POST.get('depth'), remarks = response.POST.get('remarks')).save()

    return HttpResponse('Success')
```

html user interface

```
<div>
    <form action = '/new_ship/' method = 'POST'> 
        {% csrf_token %}
            <table>
                <col>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type = 'text' name = 'ship'>Hull</input></td>
                        <td><input type = 'text' name = 'speed'>Speed</input></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>    
                        <td><input type = 'text' name = 'depth'>Depth</input></td>
                        <td><input type = 'text' name = 'remarks'>Remarks</input></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Submit Fields" id = 'button_1'></td>
                    </tr>
                </col>
            </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: can you share any traceback to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your instannce of `Hull` (`Z`) has not been saved to the database (with `.save()` ). This is the cause of the error.

You need to first create your `Hull` instance (instances are normally lower (snake) case):

```
hull = Hull.objects.create(hull = response.POST.get('ship'))
```

Then you can use that to create a `Hull_Spec` instance:

```
hull_spec = Hull_spec.objects.create(
        hull=hull,
        speed = response.POST.get('speed'), 
        depth = response.POST.get('depth'), 
        remarks = response.POST.get('remarks')
    )
```

So your view would become:

```
def new_ship (response):
    hull = Hull.objects.create(hull = response.POST.get('ship'))
    hull_spec = Hull_spec.objects.create(
        hull=hull,
        speed = response.POST.get('speed'), 
        depth = response.POST.get('depth'), 
        remarks = response.POST.get('remarks')
    )

    return HttpResponse('Success')
```

Note also, it would be convention to name your model `HullSpec` not `Hull_Spec`.

In general the two ways of saving a model instance to the db would be:

```
hull = Hull(hull="something")  # creates the instance
hull.save()    # saves it to the database

# or

hull = Hull.objects.create(hull="something")  # does it all in one go
```